# How to get specific data from a string using pattern

Tags: python, string

I'm new to python and I have this string:

```
  row =  <aa>hello</aa><bb>bello</bb><aa>great</aa><cc>today</cc><aa>later</aa><bb>fine</bb>
```

I need to get all data that is in aa :

```
hello,great,later
```

my code is:

```
 allAA  =[]
 patternAA = "<aa>(.*)</aa>"
 allAA = '\''+(re.search(patternAA, str(row))).groups() +'\','
```

and I get this result  = `<aa>hello</aa><bb>bello</bb><aa>great</aa><cc>today</cc><aa>later</aa>`
How can I get the data I need?

Comment: You need a non-greedy pattern like `patternAA = "<aa>(.*?)</aa>"`

Comment: Do you want to use regular `.find()` and `.index()` functions?

Comment: @MichaelButscher
I get this error - can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

Comment: @AniM I would love to use other options to solve it. can you please post an answer with example I'll check it and if it works i'll mark it

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/17769815) might be a relevant read. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You need to use a non-greedy capture group, specified by using `?`.
2. You should use `re.findall()` to get the captured, groups, rather than `re.search()`.

With these two fixes, we get the following:

```py
import re
row =  "<aa>hello</aa><bb>bello</bb><aa>great</aa><cc>today</cc><aa>later</aa><bb>fine</bb>"
patternAA = re.compile(r"<aa>(.*?)</aa>")
result = re.findall(patternAA, row)

# Prints ['hello', 'great', 'later']
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .findall() method that lists all matches for your regex expression

```
import re

row =  "<aa>hello</aa><bb>bello</bb><aa>great</aa><cc>today</cc><aa>later</aa><bb>fine</bb>"
allAA = re.findall(r'<aa>(.*?)</aa>', row)

print(allAA) # ['hello', 'great', 'later']
```